# and the president's first since the fall

Tags: phrase-meaning

> In an exclusive interview with ABC News' George Stephanopoulos, **and the president's first since the fall** of Afghanistan to the Taliban, President Joe Biden stood firm in his defense of the United States' withdrawal, but asserted for the first time that he believes the chaos was unavoidable.

Source: ABC News  [Biden says he did not see a way to withdraw from Afghanistan without 'chaos ensuing'](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/biden-withdraw-afghanistan-chaos-ensuing/story?id=79507930)

Does "and the president's first since the fall..." refer to "and (it is) the president's first interview (with reporters) since the fall"?

Answer (score 1):

It has two possible meanings.  It could mean "the president's first interview since the fall."  Or it could mean "the president's first exclusive interview since the fall."